# How to return phone number - email from React Native Facebook Account Kit

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, react-native, react-native-ios

Im using the Facebook Account Kit to login with phone and email in my project, the response from this login is a token, but I need to save the phone number and email in my DB, how can I getting the user email-phone used to login?

```
 componentDidMount() {
    RNAccountKit.configure({
      responseType: 'code',
      initialPhoneCountryPrefix: '+55',
      defaultCountry: 'BR',
    });
   }

 emailVerify = async () => {
     try {
      const token = await RNAccountKit.loginWithEmail();
      if (token) {
        this.setState({ verification: true });
      }
    } catch (err) {
      this.setState({ error: "Email não verificado." });
    }
  }
```

Comment: I've resolved this problem with two steps, after I receive the code from login email-phone, I sent this code to the graph account kit to take the token and hash this code with app secret and sha256, take this code (appsecret_proof) and send to new api with the token and return the object with data, those links help me : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/securing-requests , https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit/graphapi/

Answer (score 1):

You Can get account info after user logged in successfully

```
// Retrieves the logged user account info, if any user is logged
RNAccountKit.getCurrentAccount()
  .then((account) => {
    console.log(`Current account: ${account}`)
  })
```